# Windows Version Information

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How to show Windows Version Information using Delphi XE2?
I have added "System.SysUtils" in "Uses", then wrote the following codes:

```
Edit1.Text :=TOSVersion.ToString;
Edit2.Text :=TOSVersion.Name;
```

The above codes compile successfully. But the following codes do not compile.

```
Edit3.Text :=TOSVersion.Build;
Edit4.Text :=TOSVersion.Major;
Edit5.Text :=TOSVersion.Minor;
Edit6.Text :=TOSVersion.ServicePackMajor;
Edit7.Text :=TOSVersion.ServicePackMinor;
Edit8.Text :=TOSVersion.TArchitecture;
Edit9.Text :=TOSVersion.Platform;
```

My requirement is to show the windows native information only. I don't need any formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the fields that are not compiling are integers/enums, but you are trying to assign them as-is to string-based properties.  You need to format them into strings, eg:

```
const
  ArchitectureStr: array[TOSVersion.TArchitecture] of string = ('Intel X86', 'Intel X64');
  PlatformStr: array[TOSVersion.TPlatform] of string = ('Windows', 'MacOS');

...

Edit3.Text := IntToStr(TOSVersion.Build);
Edit4.Text := IntToStr(TOSVersion.Major);
Edit5.Text := IntToStr(TOSVersion.Minor);
Edit6.Text := IntToStr(TOSVersion.ServicePackMajor);
Edit7.Text := IntToStr(TOSVersion.ServicePackMinor);
Edit8.Text := ArchitectureStr[TOSVersion.Architecture];
Edit9.Text := PlatformStr[TOSVersion.Platform];
```

Comment: But the problem is that "Edit2.Text :=TOSVersion.Name;" only show as "Windows" in case of Win8. Please give any resolution.

Comment: `TOSVersion.Name` defaults to just `"Windows"` for an unknown OS version. So you are using an RTL that has not updated `TOSVersion` to recognize Win8 yet.